# Not able to create apps in Django

Tags: python, django, frameworks

I am trying to create apps in my django project. I have been getting this error in the virtual environment. But if I try to create app with out the virtual env, it works normally

```
(venv)subhash@mordor:~/backend/backend$ django-admin startapp vehicles

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/subhash/backend/venv/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
File "/home/subhash/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/subhash/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
settings.INSTALLED_APPS
File "/home/subhash/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/home/subhash/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/home/subhash/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named backend.settings.dev
```

backend is my project name.

My dev.py file

```
from backend.settings.common import *

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'django',                      
    'USER': 'tech',                   
    'PASSWORD': 'tech',              
    'HOST': 'localhost',                      
    'PORT': '5432',           
}
}

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Do you mean `settings.py` or `dev.py`?

Comment: @Bun : sometimes people use a seperate settings file for their dev stuff vs their prod stuff. its pretty common practice

Comment: I am aware of that, but the error say `No module named backend.settings.dev`.

Comment: Can you show your project layout and the location of manage.py?

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
django-admin.py startapp vehicles
```